# AJAX request with poor performance FILE UPLOAD

Tags: php, ajax

I want to make my ajax file upload faster. I'm new using AJAX, and my question is, how can i optimize my code? It's a from submit with 8 inputs and 1 file upload:
[Image of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfKmo.png)

File upload takes too long, and I want to improve it. I have 3 AJAX requests; 1 for the vars on the form, another for the file and one repetitive for the inputs if the user leaves the upload empty.

Here is my code for form submission & file upload:

```
$("#enviar").click(function(event) {
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    var nome = $("#nome").val();
    var apelido = $("#apelido").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var nome_do_negocio = $("#nome_do_negocio").val();
    var website = $("#website").val();
    var cidade = $("#cidade").val();
    var descricao = $("#descricao").val();
    var gasto = $("#gasto").val();

    console.log(nome + " " + apelido + " " + email + " " + nome_do_negocio + " " + website + " " + cidade  + " " + descricao  + " " + gasto);


    if (nome == "" || apelido == "" || email == "" || nome_do_negocio == "" || website == "" || cidade == "" || descricao == "" || gasto == "") {
        $("#error").text("Fill all inputs");
    } else {


        if (document.getElementById("file-anexo").files.length > 0) {
            var unico = 1;

            console.log("Getting File");
            var name = document.getElementById("file-anexo").files[0].name;
            var form_data = new FormData();
            var oFReader = new FileReader();
            oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("file-anexo").files[0]);
            form_data.append("file", document.getElementById('file-anexo').files[0]);
            console.log("File apppended");

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/formulario.php",
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#loader-icon').show();
                    $('.progress-bar').width('50%');
                    $('#enviar').prop('disabled', true);

                },
                data: {
                    nome: nome, 
                    apelido: apelido,
                    email: email,
                    nome_do_negocio: nome_do_negocio,
                    website: website,
                    cidade: cidade,
                    descricao: descricao,
                    gasto: gasto,
                    unico: unico,
                },
                success:function(data)
                {


                    $.ajax({
                        url: "ajax/anexo.php", 
                        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentageComplete)
                        {
                            $('.progress-bar').animate({
                                width: percentageComplete + '%'
                            }, {
                                duration: 1000
                            });
                        },
                        type: "POST",             
                        data: form_data, 
                        contentType: false,       
                        cache: false,           
                        processData:false,       
                        success: function(data)  
                        {   
                            console.log("Sucesso");
                            $('#loader-icon').hide();
                            $('.progress-bar').width('100%');
                            $('#enviar').prop('disabled', false);
                            $('.progress-bar').width('0%');
                            swal("Sucesso!", "Projeto enviado! Foi-lhe enviado um email com mais detalhes", "success");
                        }
                    });


                }

            });



        } else {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/formulario.php",
                beforeSend: function() {
                    //$('#loader-icon').show();
                    $('#enviar').prop('disabled', true);
                    $('.progress-bar').width('100%');


                },
                data: {
                    nome: nome, 
                    apelido: apelido,
                    email: email,
                    nome_do_negocio: nome_do_negocio,
                    website: website,
                    cidade: cidade,
                    descricao: descricao,
                    gasto: gasto,
                },
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#enviar').prop('disabled', false);
                    swal("Sucesso!", "Projeto enviado! Foi-lhe enviado um email com mais detalhes", "success");
                    //alert(data);
                }

            });

        }




    }

});
```

Comment: Are you uploading particularly large files?

Comment: No, 12MB files take 4-5 minutes. I have good internet.